# Missing number, treated as zero. \catcode

Tags: catcodes

I can not fix the bug.

I hope someone may help me out.

```
Missing number, treated as zero. \catcode\string`@=
Missing number, treated as zero. \catcode`\.=
Missing number, treated as zero. \catcode`\p=
Missing number, treated as zero. \catcode`\t=
Use of \@ doesn't match its definition. \@@mptopdf@@newabove
Missing number, treated as zero. \catcode`\@=
Undefined control sequence. \unprotect
```

Comment: An example of code producing the issue?

Comment: Something in your preamble seems to change the catcode of the equal sign. Are you using `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}`?

Comment: Yes I use \usepackage[turkish]{babel}

Comment: I can reproduce the error. Looks like a bug to me. As a workaround load graphicx before babel.

Comment: When I delete the commands 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics} the bug is fixed.

Comment: @andii: Note that `graphicx` loads `graphics` anyway, no need to load the latter manually. Also, please try the suggestion of Ulrike to load `graphicx` before `babel`. Best load `babel` very late in the preamble.

Comment: The next update of graphics-def will contain code to prevent the clash between the catcode settings. Until then load graphicx as I already  wrote before babel.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You should post this an an answer complete with a MWE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an incompability between graphicx and turkish:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

turkish makes the equal sign active at begin document and this leads to error when later supp-pdf.mkii is read. The problem will be resolve in the next graphicx version. A work-around until then is to load graphicx before babel:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```